# How to add an image to the bottom of a ListPointPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, image, image3d, plot-themes

I am trying to plot the points of virus outbreak along time of 3 areas. I already have the `data1`, which have 3 columns: x-coordinate, y-coordinate and time. Then I have a 3D plot as below:-

```
ListPointPlot3D[data1]
```

[image: The plot of virus outbreak]
[image]

I have an image of the map of the area concerned, and want to attach it to the bottom of the box for better illustration, is there a way to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can combine 2 graphics with `show[]`.
since you didn't provide neither the data nor the image required I used a meme I had saved as an example

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {10, 3}];

Show[{ ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {Red}]  , 
  Plot3D[0, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}, PlotStyle -> Texture[ yourfile.jpg    ]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and it really helps. May I also ask how can I raise up the image from `z=0` to `z=5`? I tried to assign `pts = {{0, 0, 5}, {0, 10, 5}, {10, 10, 5}, {10, 0, 5}};` and then run `Show[{ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> {Red}], 
  Plot3D[0, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}, PlotStyle -> {Texture[yourfile.jpg], Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> pts]}]}]`, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @HMC to raise the image you must change the value 0 to 5 in Plot3D. In addition, if you want to remove the gridlines  simply add Mesh-> None as an option at the end of Plot3D after a comma